# CSS what is the meaning of this code snippet? UPDATED

Tags: css

UPDATE

In my style sheet I have a conflict with these snippets. If I keep this one

```
 <style type="text/css">

        ::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
```

then, the gradient effect of the one below works, but the header banner is displaced towards the right. If I remove that, the header banner positions itself correctly, but the gradient effect of the code below does not work :/

```
body {

                background-image:url('../assets/uploads/miweb/gradient2.png');
                background-repeat:repeat-x;

                margin: 40px;
                font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #4F5155;
                width:600px;
                height:500px;
                margin: 0 auto;

            }

        a {
```

UPDATE II

These 3 lines

```
::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
```

have a huge impact on the rest of the page

They make this code:

```
body {



        background-image:url('../assets/uploads/miweb/gradient2.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;

        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
        width:600px;
        height:500px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }
```

be effective. If I remove those 3 lines, the gradient effect will not take effect and the font letters will not be of that family but the standard times roman. However, the negative effect is, like I said, that it displaces to the right a banner that I have as header

I have one header page, one controller and one view and the style sheet to which I have a link in the View

Comment: Don't swear at people. Ask nicely.

Answer (score 0):

That code shouldn't affect what you're doing. It is code that will change the background colour and text colour of text when it is selected by the user using their mouse.

Could you give us an example link of this happening with it commented out, please?

**EDIT**

What is the `center:` attribute supposed to be doing? It isn't valid CSS...

Comment: I am going to do a full paste of everything as I have it on my laptop, not on the web, but basically all important is already shown

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said the code doesn't affect the positioning of the elements. Only way that it can affect the header would be if that piece of code is not treated as css at all. Check if the code is in the correct style tags.

Comment: I have pasted the first chunk of the style sheet so, maybe that part should not be where it is?

Comment: @user1815822 `center:` is not valid CSS. What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: oh, yes, i remove that dont know how it popped it, but it doesnt make any difference

Comment: @user1815822 I can't see any problems with this code. If removing `center:` doesn't fix it then without having the website online for me and others to analyse, I can't tell you any more, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok thank you very much it did help a bit so at least i know i have to keep trying

Answer (score 0):

The moz is for Firefox and as stated already its for styling.  Are you using IE? as if so Id suggest trying alternate browser as well as IE has issues with the double colon which is for css3(no suprise there).  have a look [here](http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=127)
as I used this when I first came across these and it described them well.